# Pythonic way of checking if a condition holds for any element of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list in Python, and I want to check if any elements are negative. Is there a simple function or syntax I can use to apply the "is negative" check to all the elements, and see if any of them is negative? I looked through the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) and couldn't find anything similar.  The best I could come up with was:

```
if (True in [t < 0 for t in x]):
    # do something
```

I find this rather inelegant.  Is there a better way to do this in Python?

---

<sub>See also [How to check if all elements of a list match a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666163/) for checking the condition for all elements. Keep in mind that "any" and "all" checks are related [through De Morgan's law](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/), just as "or" and "and" are related.</sub>

<sub>Existing answers here use the built-in function `any` to do the iteration. See [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490) for an explanation of `any` and its counterpart, `all`.</sub>

<sub>If the condition you want to check is "is found in another container", see [How to check if one of the following items is in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740287) and its counterpart, [How to check if all of the following items are in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931541/). Using `any` and `all` will work, but more efficient solutions are possible.</sub>

Answer (score 262, accepted):

[any()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(t < 0 for t in x):
    # do something
```

Also, if you're going to use "True in ...", make it a generator expression so it doesn't take O(n) memory:

```
if True in (t < 0 for t in x):
```

Comment: Correction: If you're going to use `True in ...`, reconsider and use `any` instead.

Answer (score 41):

Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

```
if any(t < 0 for t in x):
    # do something
```

Comment: Can anyone please explain why we don't wrap the list comprehension in brackets, like so: `if any([t < 0 for t in x])` ?

Comment: I believe that's because it's a generator expression, not list comprehension. Here's [more about generator expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work).

Answer (score 11):

Python has a built in [any()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) function for exactly this purpose.