# Excel Logic Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I've developed a simple vba function to work out if someone is working after hours.  This is the original query I wrote:

```
Public Function AfterHours(StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date, ActivityDate As Date)

AfterHours = False

If (Weekday(ActivityDate) <> 1 OR Weekday(ActivityDate) <> 7) Then
    If Hour(StartTime) >= 19 Or Hour(EndTime) < 7 Then
        AfterHours = True
    End If
Else
    AfterHours = True
End If
End Function
```

This query however does not pick up staff who work on the weekend during normal business hours.  If I change it to:

```
Public Function AfterHours(StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date, ActivityDate As Date)

AfterHours = False

If (Weekday(ActivityDate) = 1 Or Weekday(ActivityDate) = 7) Then
    AfterHours = True
Else
    If Hour(StartTime) >= 19 Or Hour(EndTime) < 7 Then
        AfterHours = True
    End If
End If
End Function
```

The query functions correctly.  The logic for both is the same, just inverted.  In the first function if it is not the weekend it should test whether it is outside business hours, otherwise it is the weekend and should be flagged.  The second function checks if it is the weekend and flags it, otherwise it checks whether it is outside business hours.

I don't understand why these queries return different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `If` statement is wrong.

```
If (Weekday(ActivityDate) <> 1 OR Weekday(ActivityDate) <> 7) Then
```

Because you use `Or` this will always be true.  Use `And` instead.

Comment: Ah, I see my issue I assumed that  Weekday(ActivityDate) <> 1 Or Weekday(ActivityDate) <> 7 is equivalent to NOT(Weekday(ActivityDate) = 1 Or Weekday(ActivityDate) = 7)

Comment: +1 see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2168603/53614) for more details