# Do all? and any? guarantee short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: ruby

Testing out some code in both `pry` and `irb`, I get the following results:

```
[1] pry(main)> a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 0]
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 0]
[2] pry(main)> a.any? {|obj| p obj; 3 / obj > 1}
1
=> true
[3] pry(main)> a.all? {|obj| p obj; 3 / obj > 1}
1
3
=> false
```

In `[2]` and `[3]` I see that there appears to be short-circuit evaluation that aborts the iteration as soon as possible, but is this guaranteed behaviour? Reading the documentation there is no mention of this behaviour. I realise that I can use `inject` instead as that will iterate over everything, but I'm interested in finding out what the official Ruby view is.

Comment: What do you mean by `garanteed`? In [2] it stopped evalution when it found any one, that is > then 1. I don't see any reason why it should go further. The same for [3], when it found any that is false it stopped. There are a lot of other methods to evaluate through whole sentence of objects...

Comment: I mean that since the array has a zero in it, if I use `inject` I get a `ZeroDivisionError`, but will a conforming Ruby implementation (assuming there is a specification to conform to!) always stop at the earliest possible point and never try to divide by zero?

Comment: I believe it is not even defined that `any?` or `all?` go through the array from start to end. To be save across ruby versions, you can't make such assumptions. For a single ruby version that might be OK.

Comment: I think @tessi made the essential point: there is no requirement for any method that returns true or false to traverse a collection in any particular order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

In the final [draft](http://www.ipa.go.jp/osc/english/ruby/ruby_draft_specification_agreement.html) of the Ruby standard, `all?` is defined as such:

1. Invoke the method `each` on the receiver
2. For each element X which the method `each` yeilds:

   1. If block is given, call block with X as argument. If this call returns a falseish object, *return* **false**.
   2. If block is not given, and X is a falseish object, *return* **false**.
3. Return **true**.

Note the word *return* in step 2. This guarantees short circuit evaluation. `any?` is defined similarly. However the standard is still a draft and I don't know which Ruby implementations (if any) aim to be standards-compliant.

Comment: "However the standard is still a draft" – The JIS standard was published by JSA on 2011-03-22: https://webdesk.jsa.or.jp/books/W11M0090/index/?bunsyo_id=JIS%20X%203017:2013 Then passed on to ISO, which published it on 2012-02-14: https://iso.org/standard/59579.html JSA then published a revision aligning its standard with the version published by ISO on 2013-12-20. So, the original JIS standard published by JSA was published almost three years before your answer.

Comment: "I don't know which Ruby implementations (if any) aim to be standards-compliant." – The only implementation explicitly based on the ISO spec is MRuby. The spec was created in a descriptive fashion, i.e. by describing what implementations are *actually* doing. In particular, the spec was designed such that existing implementations are conforming to the spec without any changes, which means that any major implementation in existence at the time the spec was created (2009-2010) is automatically compliant, this includes MRI, YARV, Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, MagLev, MacRuby, Ruby.NET, XRuby, …

Comment: … and probably a couple I forgot. Note that, however, this obviously only applies to the state in 2009. Since then, implementations may have changed (for example, Rubinius has become very opinionated, and in some cases deviates from standard Ruby when they disagree with decisions made by the Ruby designers), and of course Ruby may have changed (frozen string literals come to mind). At some point, I think it will be impossible to be both compliant with ISO/JSA Ruby and current Ruby, and implementations *will* choose current Ruby. (It doesn't look like there is real incentive updating ISO Ruby.)

Answer (score 5):

The [`any?` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) just realizes the '**or**' logic function over the `Enumerable`. It could be interpreted as statement:

> y = x1 v x2 v x3 v ... v xn

And the [`all?` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) realizes '**and**' logic function over the `Enumerable`. It also could be interpreted as statement:

> y = x1 * x2 * x3 * ... * xn

Since the `Array` is an `Enumerable`, it also includes those methods. So, for the method `any?` the first occurience of `true` (exactly neither `nil` nor `false`) result breaks enumeration with `true` result. In example the *yielded* becomes *true* on number *4*, so the methods breaks the execution the returns `true`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].any? {| x | puts x ; x > 3 }
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# => true
```

Also you can apply [DeMorgan's rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/demorgan-rules-explained) to the function `any?`, and to use `all?` method:

```
![1,2,3,4,5].all? {| x | puts x ; x <= 3 }
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# => true
```

For the method `all?` the first occurience of either `false` or `nil` result do something similar, i.e. returns `false`. In example the *yielded* becomes *false* on number *3*, so the methods breaks the execution the returns `false`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].all? {| x | puts x ; x < 3 }
# 1
# 2
# 3
# => false
```

And with [DeMorgan's transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/demorgan-rules-explained) to use `any?` method:

```
![1,2,3,4,5].any? {| x | puts x ; x >= 3 }
# 1
# 2
# 3
# => false
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some ambiguity here.

Consider the following:

```rb
RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.3.7"
```

When yielding to a block:

```rb
[1,2,3,4,5].all? {| x | puts x ; x < 3 }
# 1
# 2
# 3
# => false
```

When not yielding to a block:

```rb
def a
  puts "in a"
  true
end

def b
  puts "in b" 
  false
end

def c
  puts "in c"
  true
end

[a,b,c].all?
# in a
# in b
# in c
# => false
```

Seems like condition #2:

> [If block is not given, and X is a falseish object, return false.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20688735/1822555)

Is not valid.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm running into now (though I am on Ruby 2.6.6).  My code is definitely _*NOT*_ short circuiting when there is no block given.

Comment: This is not doing what you think it's doing. Each method is called during the list creation. So those puts are being called before all? is called.