# Ruby blocks - unless and if comparison

Tags: ruby, block

I have a doubt regarding unless and if blocks in ruby language. Please excuse me if I'm that stupid to ask this question.

Lets assume we have two boolean variables `a = true` and `b = true`.

condition: I want to check whether both of them are true. Using if statement we can check that as given below.

```
if a == true && b == true
  print "Hai"
end
```

doubt: instead of the above statement, can I use the one given below?

```
unless a == false && b == false
  print "Hai"
end
```

Will both the blocks given above give the same result?

Comment: they are called if block not the loops

Comment: You could try the 4 possible combinations yourself.

Comment: Hey, may be because your teacher was great!! But, please do not mock upon others even though you are a genius. Thanks :)-

Comment: @sawa in India we learn that too . may be he do not know how to apply that in programming :)

Comment: Friendly advice: [Making sense with Ruby's "unless"](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2699-making-sense-with-rubys-unless)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
if a == true && b == true
  print "Hai"
end
```

you can write

```
if a && b
  print "Hai"
end
```

This is the same as

```
unless !(a && b)
  print "Hai"
end
```

Which is (using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) the same as

```
unless !a || !b
  print "Hai"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

No, and it comes from [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Firstly, if you check boolean value, you don't need this weird construction `a == true`, it's sufficient to use

```
if a && b
```

Secondly, `!(a && b) == !a || !b` (this part comes from De Morgan's laws), so if you want to use unless and you want it to be equivalent to the previous `if` expression, you should use it this way:

```
unless !a || !b
```

Since it's quite messy, you should stay with `if a && b`.

Answer (score 1):

`if` is not *loop* if is check condition operator:

```
if a == true && b == true
  print "Hai"
end
```

Make sure that you differ `=` and `==` operator, because `=` is assign operator, `==` is condition operator, which returns `true` or `false` results that are ruby classes. To make it as a loop do:

```
while true
  if a == true && b == true
    print "Hai"
  else
    break
  end
end
```

Which can be simpified to:

```
while a && b
  print "Hai"
end
```

`unless` operator is also check condition keyword as `if`, and it can be represented as `if !` or `if not`. You can transform condition for `if` operator with the negated condition for `unless` operator using [DeMorgan's rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/demorgan-rules-explained). In your case it shell be as:

```
unless a == false || b == false # not &&
  print "Hai"
end
```

or if you do a loop:

```
while true
  unless a == false || b == false
    print "Hai"
  else
    break
  end
end
```

And in the simplified form:

```
while !( a == false || b == false )
  print "Hai"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if a == true and b == false then `a == false and b == false` is false.

Therefore, `unless a == false and b == false` is true

but b == false

So no, it's not the same :)

Answer (score 0):

I you want to test out code. Best thing in ruby is to spin up an instance of `irb`.

The interactive ruby bash can be used to test those assumptions.

Next thing is the usage of `a_boolean == true`. This is not considered good style in ruby. Just write `a_boolean` or `!a_boolean`.

Another thing is that "loops" are a different thing that "conditions".

loops -> while, until, etc

conditions -> if, unless, etc

Short answer to your question. `unless` is the opposite of `if`, it is `!if`

Answer (score 0):

thats not a loop, its a if statement or block

```
if a and b
   print 'hi'
end
```

if you to not compare bits, dont use &&. use "and" instead.
also if a means the same as if a == true

```
unless a and b # unless ( a and b ) is the same
   print 'hi'
end
```

to write the meaning down its something like

if not ( a and b ) then

hope this helps.