# AND and OR are switched?

Tags: python

I want to create two random sets and compare them to two other sets.
The programm should stop when both sets are the same as the other two sets.
This is a boiled down version of the code i'm having trouble with:

```
import random
random.seed()

a = set()
b = set()
c = set()
d = set()

for i in range(3):
    a.add(random.randint(1,10))
    b.add(random.randint(1,10))

while a!=c and b!=d:
    c.clear()
    d.clear()
    for i in range(3):
        c.add(random.randint(1,10))
        d.add(random.randint(1,10))

print(a,b)
print(c,d)
```

The exact line with my problem:
`while a!=c and b!=d:`

With "and" the loop already stops when just one pair of sets are the same.
When i switch the "and" for "or" it does exacly what i want, i just don't understand why?
Can somebody please explane.

Comment: Which sets need to be equivalent for the program to halt?

Comment: I think we need a canonical question about De Morgan's laws...

Comment: Your loop runs "while `a` is different from `c` and `b` is different from `d`". So yes, it stops when two sets are equal. That's what you told it to do.

Comment: Perhaps [_deMorgan rules explained_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/demorgan-rules-explained) @Aran-Fey?

Comment: @ChristianDean That's probably too confusing to be of any use :P

Comment: Yeah, I figured it might be a bit to technical @Aran-Fey. To be honest, I become a bit confused reading the top answer as well :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition holds when **both** `a` is not `c` and `b` is not `d`. As soon  as one pair is equal then the *`and`* fails and the loop is broken.

As you have identified you could use an `or` which will work, but it may be more clear to use:

```
while not (a == c and b == d):
    ...
```

which works exactly how you would say it!

Answer (score 1):

Think about it. You have the condition:

```
a != c and b != d
```

What exactly is this condition telling Python? Well, we can see it uses the `and` operator. The `and` operator will *only* return `True`, *if* both of its conditions are true. From this, we can see that the above condition will only return true if both the `a` set is ***not equal*** to the `c` set ***and*** the `b` set is ***not equal*** to the `d` set.

So what would happen when one pair of sets becomes equal? **The above condition will fail**. Since one of the comparisons between two sets would return `False`, rather than `True`,  `and` will also return false, since *both* of its conditions *are not true*.

What you actually want is this:

```
not (a == c and b == d)
```

I'll leave it as an exercise up to you to figure why the above condition works, whereas `a != c and b != d` does not.

Answer (score 0):

While loops repeat when the statement is True, in this case when either `a != c` or`b != d`evaluates to `False`, so will the while loop argument. 
You want to alter the logic, change:

```
a != c and b !=d
```

to:

```
not (a == c and b == d)
```

or:

```
a != c or b != d
```

This will achieve what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
while not (a == c and b == d):
    #code
```