# do while loops keepings repeating

Tags: c++, do-while

Trying to test if input is "TF" or "MC". The while condition keeps coming out as true even though argument is written: line != "TF" || line != "MC"

Not understanding how the loop keeps repeating even though I input TF or MC. I have also verified that the tranform method is making the string capital.

```
do {

    cout << "\nEnter the Question type (TF) for True/False or (MC) for Multiple Choice:\n";
    getline(cin, line);
    transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), ::toupper);

    } while (line != "TF" || line != "MC");
```

I expected the loop to only initiate once and exit.

Comment: `line != "TF" || line != "MC"` is always true. Perhaps you want `line != "TF" && line != "MC"`

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/demorgan-rules-explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the person types "MC", the expression

`line != "TF"`

will be set to true, which will make the OR statement true.

(And thus repeating the while even though the person typed a valid answer)

What you are looking for is to check if the answer is neither one of the options, which can be checked as follows:

`(line != "TF" && line != "MC")`

The opposite would be reasonable too. That is, to check if the person typed a valid answer, and keep repeating it while it is not the case:

`while(!(line == "TF" || line == "MC"))`

Both statements are equivalent, as stated in the comments, by the [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but it does explain the relationships between the OR, AND, and NOT operators: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra