# Why can I not use && when finding the LCM of three numbers?

Tags: java

*Note: The program works as intended.*

I made a program in Java to calculate the LCM of 3 numbers. Initially, I programmed my with the condition `while( num1 != num3 && num1!=num2 && num3!=num2)`. My initial reasoning was that the loop should stop when all of the numbers were the same.

In an attempt to guess, I changed `&&` to `||` as a last resort, but still do not understand its logic.

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Type your 1st number :");
int num1=input.nextInt();
System.out.print("Type your 2nd number :");
int num2=input.nextInt();
System.out.print("Type your 3rd number :");
int num3=input.nextInt();
int n=num1; 
int m=num2;
int b=num3;
  
while( num1 != num3 || num1!=num2 || num3!=num2){
     if (num2 > num1 || num3 > num1)
          num1 += n;
     if (num1 > num2)
          num2 += m;          
     if (num2 > num3)
          num3 += b;
}    

System.out.println("LCM of "+"'"+n+"'"+" and "+"'"+m+"'"+" and "+"'"+b+"'"+" is "+num3);
```

Comment: If you use `&&`, you're requiring that _all_ of the numbers are different. If you use `||` you're requiring that any of the numbers are different.

Comment: `a && b && c` means *all* conditions must be true. In your case this means all numbers must be different. `a || b|| c` means *at least one* condition must be true. In your case this means at least two of the three numbers must be different. So for the first case, your program stops when two of the numbers become equal, in the second case it only stops when all three are equal

Comment: See [De Morgan's rules explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2168603/3890632)

Comment: @derpirscher * in the second case it only stops when all three are equal* , but why ive connected the statements with "OR" , doesnt that mean that one of the statements should turn true for the process to stop ?

Comment: No. The loop continues while one of the conditions is true

Answer (score 0):

> Initially, I programmed my with the condition `while( num1 != num3 && num1!=num2 && num3!=num2)`. My initial reasoning was that the loop
> should stop when all of the numbers were the same.

The loop will stop when any of the two numbers are the same. See the explanation given below:

Assuming **num1 = num2 = 5 and num3 = 10**,

```
5 != 10 && num1!=num2 && num3!=num2 => true && 5!=5 && num3!=num2 => true && false && num3!=num2 => false && num3!=num2 => false
```

Assuming **num1 = num3 = 5 and num2 = 10**,

```
5 != 5 && num1!=num2 && num3!=num2 => false && num1!=num2 && num3!=num2 => false
```

Assuming **num1 = 10 and num2 = num3 = 5**,

```
10 != 5 && num1!=num2 && num3!=num2 => true && 10!=5 && num3!=num2 => true && true && num3!=num2 => true && 5!=5 => true && false => false
```

Assuming **num1 = num2 = num3 = 5**,

```
5 != 5 && num1!=num2 && num3!=num2 => false && num1!=num2 && num3!=num2 => false
```

Note that when more than two conditions are joined with `&&` the evaluation **stops** as soon as any of the condition (from left to right) evaluates to `false`.

> In an attempt to guess, I changed `&&` to `||` as a last resort, but
> still do not understand its logic.

In this case, the loop will stop only when all the numbers are the same. See the explanation given below:

Assuming **num1 = num2 = 5 and num3 = 10**,

```
5 != 10 || num1!=num2 || num3!=num2 => true || num1!=num2 || num3!=num2 => true
```

Assuming **num1 = num3 = 5 and num2 = 10**,

```
5 != 5 || num1!=num2 || num3!=num2 => false || 5!=10 || num3!=num2 => false || true || num3!=num2 => true || num3!=num2  => true
```

Assuming **num1 = 10 and num2 = num3 = 5**,

```
10 != 5 || num1!=num2 || num3!=num2 => true || num1!=num2 || num3!=num2 => true
```

Assuming **num1 = num2 = num3 = 5**,

```
5 != 5 || num1!=num2 || num3!=num2 => false || 5!=5 || num3!=num2 => false || false || 5!=5 => false || false => false
```

Note that when more than two conditions are joined with `||` the evaluation **stops** as soon as any of the condition (from left to right) evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Sorry but I dont really get what you are trying to say

Comment: @tin - You have mentioned, `The program works as intended.` and you wanted to understand how the `&&` and `||` operators work when multiple of them are used in a single expression. I wrote this answer to explain that. I'm sure you can understand every bit of it if you read the answer wholeheartedly. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.