# Error of wrong char, even when the char is correct

Tags: c, if-statement, char, logical-or, logical-and

I have an assignment on matrix operations and I cannot figure out what is wrong in my code, that makes my program say that char is wrong, even though it is correct. Could you please help me?
Thank You.

```
if(scanf(" %c", &symbol) == 1)              //input symbol with error handling
    {
        if (symbol != '*' || symbol != '+' || symbol != '-')
        {
            printf("[%c]\n", symbol);
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Chybny vstup [Symbol]!\n");
            return 100;
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiebL.png)

Comment: Please give complete code as a [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result. Please do not post text as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: `if (symbol != '*' || symbol != '+' || symbol != '-')` should have `&&` not `||`.

Comment: Well, if you entered `'*'` then it isn't a `'+'`. Try using `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Maybe removing space before %c works. It should become "%c"

Comment: @SeyedMohammadAminAtyabi the space correctly filters any leading whitespace in the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [De Morgan's rules explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/de-morgans-rules-explained)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the logical AND operator `&&` instead of the logical OR operator `||`

```
if (symbol != '*' && symbol != '+' && symbol != '-')
```

Otherwise the condition of the if statement

```
if (symbol != '*' || symbol != '+' || symbol != '-')
```

will always evaluate to logical true for any character.

You could avoid the mistake if you used the negation operator the following way

```
if ( !( symbol == '*' || symbol == '+' || symbol == '-' ) )
```