# Multiple date conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with multiple date conditions. If someone was born in 1911-1914 and he had a citizenship issued before 1922 it should be cancelled, otherwise they can keep it.

```
citizenship = datetime(year=1920, month=4, day=15)
dob = datetime(year=1910, month=5, day=5)

cit_start = datetime(year=1918, month=1, day=1)
cit_end = datetime(year=1922, month=12, day=31)
dob_start = datetime(year=1911, month=1, day=31)
dob_end = datetime(year=1914, month=12, day=31)

if not dob_start <= dob <= dob_end and not cit_start <= citizenship <= cit_end:
    print("keep it")
else:
    print("cancelled")
```

How could the resolution go to else only if both of the conditions are True?

Comment: `if not (dob_start<=dob<=dob_end and cit_start<=citizenship<=cit_end):`

Comment: Google "De Morgan's Laws"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [De Morgan's rules explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/de-morgans-rules-explained)

Comment: Write the condition the same way you said it in your text.

Comment: Why do you have a `cit_start` variable? You just said citizenship before 1922. Where does 1918 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it the same way you said in the question, instead of trying to invert it:

```
if dob_start <= dob <= dob_end and cit_start <= citizenship <= cit_end:
    print("cancelled")
else:
    print("keep it")
```