# Question about when to use "&" and "|" (OR) when using conditional operators "==" and "!=" in the dplyr::filter() function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, operators

I'm asking this question more out of curiosity. I was able to achieve my desired results using the filter() function but I'm interested in the explanation for the scenario below.

I wanted to use filter() to filter out values with multiple conditions using the != operator.  I first tried using OR "|" but it wasn't correctly filtering out the values. It instead returned all the data back seemingly unfiltered. However, it worked when I used "&" instead (see below).

Ex.

```
data %>% 
  filter(SampleTypeName != "Grab" & 
         SampleTypeName != "Composite" & 
         SampleTypeName != "Integrated" & 
         SampleTypeName != "Not Applicable")
```

When I wanted to basically do the opposite, I filtered for values equal to the same set of strings above. I intuitively thought using "&" was also the solution. It instead returned all the data back seemingly unfiltered as well. Turns out, to achieve my desired results, I had to use "|" instead.

Ex.

```
data %>% 
  filter(SampleTypeName == "Grab" | 
         SampleTypeName == "Composite" | 
         SampleTypeName == "Integrated" |
         SampleTypeName == "Not Applicable")
```

Why is this the case? I would appreciate both a semi-in-depth explanation and an explanation like I'm five :)

Thanks

Comment: I believe the syntax you want is: `data %>%  filter(!SampleTypeName %in% c("Grab", "Composite", "Integrated", "Not Applicable"))`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to know about `dplyr::filter` is that multiple expressions can be combined by a comma, which is the same as using "&". For example:

```
data %>% 
  filter(SampleTypeName != "Grab", SampleTypeName != "Composite")
```

However as indicated in the comment from @jon-spring, the better way to test for multiple string values is to use `%in%`. So your first example becomes:

```
data %>% 
  filter(!SampleTypeName %in% c("Grab", "Composite", "Integrated", "Not Applicable"))
```

And the second example, you simply remove the negation.

```
data %>% 
  filter(SampleTypeName %in% c("Grab", "Composite", "Integrated", "Not Applicable"))
```

As to why "|" did not work as expected in the first example: it is because every row is evaluated against each condition. Let's say your variable, `x` can take values of "a" or "b". Now ask the question: "is x not equal to a OR is x not equal to b". The first part of that question will keep rows where x is "b" and the second part of that question will keep rows where x is "a". In other words, all rows are kept, as you observed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a quirk of `dplyr` - this is an application of [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) in propositional logic which states that ¬A∧¬B ⇔ ¬(A∨B). In plain english, this rule states that **not A and not B = not (A or B)**. In R terms, this means that `!(a & b) == !a | !b` and conversely, `!(a | b) == !a & !b`. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/de-morgans-rules-explained) for a great, easy-to-understand explanation.

In your specific case, you are combining lots of negations with `&` which looks like `!A & !B & !C & !D`. By DeMorgan's Law, we know that this is equal to `!(A | B | C | D)`. To get the negation of this, we simply remove the `!`, so we are left with `A | B | C | D`.