# How to use OR operator with not equal to condition

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a snippet to get results for OR with NOT EQUAL condition but my code isn't working.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345;34567;67890 | Text |
| 34567;98765;65432 | Text |

My condition is the cell should NOT contain 12345 OR 67890. So ideally I want FALSE for first row and TRUE for second row. Below is the code I wrote

```
(~F.col("Col1").like("%12345%")) | (~F.col("Col1").like("%67890%"))
```

But the result from the above code is TRUE for both the rows. Will someone please correct me where I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/de-morgans-rules-explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`rlike`](https://%20https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.rlike.html) with the *pipe/or* (`|`):

```
out = df.withColumn("Result", ~F.col("Col1").rlike("12345|67890"))
```

Or following your approach, you need to add the missing parenthesis :

```
(~(F.col("Col1").like("%12345%")) | ~(F.col("Col1").like("%67890%")))
```

​
Out :

```
out.show(truncate=False)
​
+-----------------+----+------+
|Col1             |Col2|Result|
+-----------------+----+------+
|12345;34567;67890|Text|false |
|34567;98765;65432|Text|true  |
+-----------------+----+------+
```

Comment: Adding/Removing Parenthesis didn't heled for sure but rlike was what I needed. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use XOR to evaluate that only one of the conditions its true.

```
condition1 = F.col("Col1").like("%12345%")
condition2 = F.col("Col1").like("%67890%")

result = (condition1 & ~(condition2)) | (~(condition1) & condition2)
```

Output of: `df.withColumn("Result", result).show()`:

| Col1 | Col2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345;34567;67890 | Text | false |
| 34567;98765;65432 | Text | false |
| 12345;98765;65432 | Text | true |

#### pyspark **when**:

```
condition1 = F.col("Col1").like("%12345%")
condition2 = F.col("Col1").like("%67890%")

result = (
    F.when(condition1 & ~condition2, "Condition 1 True")
    .when(~condition1 & condition2, "Condition 2 True")
    .otherwise("Neither condition is True")
)
```

Output of: `df.withColumn("Result", result).show()`:

| Col1 | Col2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345;34567;67890 | Text | Neither condition... |
| 34567;98765;65432 | Text | Neither condition... |
| 12345;98765;65432 | Text | Condition 1 True |

### XOR works this way:

```
True ^ True == False
True ^ False == True
False ^ True == True
False ^ False == False
```

You can negate the value to obtain true if both of the conditions are the same value:

```
not (condition ^ condition)
```

Example:

```
not (True ^ True) == True
not (True ^ False) == False
not (False ^ True) == False
not (False ^ False) == True
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the logic. But I'm getting below error:
"^ is not a supported operation for types Column and Column. Please review your code."

Comment: @SaurabhShelar Modified to use pyspark "when"

Comment: @SaurabhShelar improved

Comment: @Fake Venturi My expected output is a Boolean value. I feel your workaround is little extra as what if we have multiple conditions to be satisfied instead of just 2 as in this case. I'm looking for a solution which gives me a Boolean value FALSE even if one of the condition is FALSE.

Comment: `(~F.col("Col1").like("%12345%")) & (~F.col("Col1").like("%67890%"))` True if it contains neither, False if it contains one or both. @SaurabhShelar

Answer (score 0):

> My condition is the cell should NOT contain 12345 OR 67890.

Despite the way we express this in everyday English, you should just use & instead of |.

The logic is that the string does not contain 12345 and it also does not contain 67809.