# Not x and not y = not (x or y)?

Tags: truthtable

[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ8FS.jpg)

`F (x,y,z) = ¬x¬y , and G(x,y,z) = ¬(x + y)`
is `F(x,y,z) = G(x,y,z)` ?

Will we get the same truth table output?

This is the truth table outputs that I got and it’s not equal but others say it equal, I’m not sure how can it be equal?

F(x,y,z) = not x and not y
Both x and y need to be 0
And z is ignored.

G(x,y,z) = not (x or y)
At least one of x or y need to be 0
And z is also ignored.

Am I doing something wrong here?

[My truth tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSlk3.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [De Morgan's rules explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/de-morgans-rules-explained)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"not x" is true if x is false.
"not y" is true if y is false.
So, "not x and not y" is true only if both x and y are false.

On the other hand, "not (x or y)" is true if the entire expression inside the parentheses (x or y) is false. This happens only when both x and y are false.

Therefore, "not x and not y" is logically equivalent to "not (x or y)."
or,
¬x∧¬y is equivalent to ¬(x∨y) in terms of boolean logic.