# Easiest way to filter a list

Tags: python

I have an API that returns store availability for an `Item`, The product should be considered `Ready To Purchase` if any of the stores return 200, and `Not Ready` to every other status codes (Including 404).

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "sku": "svk__21w",
  "store_data": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "reason": "no product found, or product is not available, or not in inventory"
    },
    {
      "status": 404,
      "reason": "no product found, or product is not available, or not in inventory"
    },
    {
      "status": 404,
      "reason": "no product found, or product is not available, or not in inventory"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, In my code, To check If this product is indeed `Ready To Purchase` or not, I use a `for` loop:

```
is_product_available = False
for store in data['store_data']:
   if 'data' in store and store['status'] == 200:
        print("Product state is ready to purchase")

        is_product_available = True
   else:
        print("Product state is not ready to purchase")
```

Which works, But I think it's just bad design, In the future, With more stores opening..

**What I want:**

- A better way to check if any of the stores have `data` and their code is `200` and if so, the product is `Ready To Purchase`.

Example of a Ready To Purchase product:

```
store_data: 
   store_1: 404
   store_2: 404
   store_3 200
```

Example of a Not Ready To Purchase product:

```
store_data: 
   store_1: 404
   store_2: 404
   store_3 404
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `if 'data' in store`? None of the stores have a `'data'` key. How can be this works for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way of checking if a condition holds for any element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342601/pythonic-way-of-checking-if-a-condition-holds-for-any-element-of-a-list)

Comment: @Tomerikoo sometimes data is in store, but the status code is different.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I know, Like I said, sometimes one of the stores report availability and has `data` in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function

```
is_product_available = any([store['status'] == 200 for store in data['store_data']])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use function `any` and a generator expression to do that most efficiently like

```py
is_ready = any(d.get("status", 0) == 200 for d in data['store_data'])
```

this will return True once it found the first match that is true. So if there are 10_000 entries and the first is already 200, it will only have to check that.