# Print only one False or one True when needed

Tags: python, function

I am writing a function that accepts a list of scores and when the `j` number is bigger than the average of all the numbers before it, at least once, it returns `True`, otherwise it returns `False`.

My only problem is that when I enter for example `[1,1,1,9999]` it returns False False True, I want only one True without the Falses. And for example, entering `[1,1,2,2,3]` returns 4 times False, I only need False once. How do I do that?

### My code:

```
def Outstanding_Scores(scores):
    
    for j in range(0,len(scores)-1):
        if sum(scores[j::-1])//len(scores[j::-1]) < scores[j+1]:
            print('True')
            break
        else:
            print('False')
             
            
scoresInput = input().split(',')
scoreslist = [int(i) for i in scoresInput]

Outstanding_Scores(scoreslist)
```

### EDIT: My code

```
def Outstanding_Scores(scores):
    
    for j in range(0,len(scores)-1):
        return True if (sum(scores[j::-1])//len(scores[j::-1]) < scores[j+1]) else False
            
scoresInput = input().split(',')
scoreslist = [int(i) for i in scoresInput]

suspicious_income(scoreslist)
```

Comment: Note that your function doesn't return `True` or `False`, it just prints those strings (and actually returns `None`). Printing and returning are not the same thing.

Comment: I made some edits to my code,  thank you for the note. Now however it returns False all the time, even if the condition is true. @ndc85430

Comment: [Pythonic way of checking if a condition holds for any element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1342601)

Comment: You state "all the numbers before it", but you evaluate all the numbers after it (and including). Please read up on list indexing: -1 after two colons doesn't mean the indexing is reversed, just the result.

Comment: you should return `True` after `for`-loop, not in `else`. OR you should change indentation to create special construction `for/else` instead of normal `if/else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `print(True)` or `return True` after `for`-loop, not in `else`

```
def Outstanding_Scores(scores):
    
    for j in range(0,len(scores)-1):
        if sum(scores[j::-1])//len(scores[j::-1]) < scores[j+1]:
            return True

    # --- after loop ---

    return False

# --- main ---

print( Outstanding_Scores([1,1,1,9999]) )  # True
print( Outstanding_Scores([1,1,2,2,3]) )   # True
```

---

**EDIT:**

I think you have other mistakes in your code.

```
def Outstanding_Scores(scores):

    # --- before loop ---

    if len(scores) < 2:
        return False

    # --- loop ---
    
    for j in range(1, len(scores)):
        
        current  = scores[j]
        previous = scores[:j]
        
        average = sum(previous) / len(previous)

        print(f'j: {j:2} | val: {current:5} | average: {average:5} | previous: {previous} | {current > average}')
        
        if current > average:
            return True

    # --- after loop ---

    return False

print( Outstanding_Scores([1,1,1,9999]) )  # True
print( Outstanding_Scores([1,1,2,2,3]) )   # True
print( Outstanding_Scores([1,1,1,1]) )     # False
```

Result:

```
j:  1 | val:     1 | average:   1.0 | previous: [1] | False
j:  2 | val:     1 | average:   1.0 | previous: [1, 1] | False
j:  3 | val:  9999 | average:   1.0 | previous: [1, 1, 1] | True
True
j:  1 | val:     1 | average:   1.0 | previous: [1] | False
j:  2 | val:     2 | average:   1.0 | previous: [1, 1] | True
True
j:  1 | val:     1 | average:   1.0 | previous: [1] | False
j:  2 | val:     1 | average:   1.0 | previous: [1, 1] | False
j:  3 | val:     1 | average:   1.0 | previous: [1, 1, 1] | False
False
```