# Comparing a set of IP addresses against subnets using python and netaddr module

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to get a list of IP addresses if they match a subnet via Python 2.7 and netaddr module.

I am currently running this on my Windows PC with Python 2.7 installed from the www.python.org site.

I intend to run it on RHEL 6.x with python 2.7 installed.

This should take the IP address from `ip_list` and compare it to the `banned_subnets`
if it finds a match then it should add these to `new_list` and print out `Match found`.

There should be two matches

```
10.11.117.137 is in subnet 10.11.117.0/24
10.24.33.21 is in subnet 10.24.33.0/24
```

I can't fathom out checking multiple values in a list against a list with multiple values.

I have read the docs on `netaddr`, I have read the [Python - Comparing two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138015/python-comparing-two-lists) on this site and several others but I am just not getting it.

Here is the bit of code I am trying to get to work

```
import netaddr

# Range of IP Addresses that we see connections from.
ip_list = ['10.11.117.137', '10.11.122.20', '10.24.33.21', '10.11.122.22']

# List of IP Subnets that members of IP list should not be from.
banned_subnets = ['10.11.117.0/24', '10.24.33.0/24']

# Using banned_subnets as our master list see if any of the ip_list addresses are present
# If they are present print the ip address

new_list = []

for Z in banned_subnets:
    for X in ip_list:
        if netaddr.IPAddress(X) == netaddr.IPNetwork(Z):
            new_list.append(X)
            print 'Match Found'
        else:
            print 'No Matches Found'

print new_list
```

When I run this i get the following returned

```
E:\Python27\python.exe E:/Users/twelsh/PycharmProjects/lool/liist-loop.py
Match Found
Match Found
Match Found
Match Found
Match Found
Match Found
Match Found
Match Found
['10.11.117.137', '10.11.122.20', '10.24.33.21', '10.11.122.22', '10.11.117.137', '10.11.122.20', '10.24.33.21', '10.11.122.22']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm new to all this Python malarky. All advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set [`intersection`](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_03.html#unions-intersections-and-differences) with `&` operator and save result to list.

```
new_list = [str(ip) for ip in netaddr.IPSet(ip_list) & (netaddr.IPSet(banned_subnets))]
print new_list
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work although it returns 3510 'No Matches Found' from a list of 90 IP Addresses in the 'ip_list' and 39 subnets in the 'banned_subnets' Is there a more efficient way of doing this loop as it burns time looping over all addresses for every banned subnet?

Comment: Edited answer with more efficient algorithm.