# Python: check if list is contained in another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have two lists that look like this:

```
list1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
```

How can I check if the second list is contained in the first? I assume sets would not work, because the letters can be repeated.

Comment: Does order matter, or simply the number of occurrences of values?

Comment: @eestrada the order does not matter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Comparing two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138015/python-comparing-two-lists)

Comment: So in this case, the expect outpu should be False or True?

Comment: @KevinGuan In this case, False. Only two a's in the first list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets won't work if the frequency matter but counting the frequency will:

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
cn1, cn2 = Counter(list1), Counter(list2)
print(all(cn2[k] <= v for k, v in cn1.items()))
```

If the count of each string in list2 is <= to the amount of times it appears in list1 you have all the strings from list2 in list1, which for the lists in your question would return False but for,

```
list1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
list2 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
```

would return `True` as you have the same amount of a's and a b.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will return True only when the lists are identical.

Comment: @shomz,  I edited, so you want to basically see if you could make up the first list by using elements in the second?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Padraic_Cunningham's answer:

```
from collections import Counter

def contained(l1, l2):
    cntr1 = Counter(list1)
    cntr2 = Counter(list2)
    for k in cntr2:
        if cntr2[k] != cntr1.get(k):
            return False
    return True

list1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']

contained(list1, list2)
```