# Python: comparing two iterables element wise with different type

Tags: python, list, functional-programming, python-itertools, iterable

I'd like to compare two sorted lists element wise and handle each case differently:

1. If both iterables contain the an element, I'd like to call `update_func`.
2. If only the left iterable contains an element, I'd like to call `left_surplus_func`.
3. If only the right iterable contains an element, I'd like to call `right_surplus_func`.

Unfortunately, `zip` doesn't help me in this case, because it would create tuples of unrelated elements. Also, in my case, both lists or iterables are of different and nonconvertible types.

This is similar to [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches) and [Checking if any elements in one list are in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138015/python-comparing-two-lists), but not close enough to be a real solution.

I came up with a working solution (except both iterables must not contain `None`):

```
def compare_iterables_elemet_wise(left, right, compare_func,
                          left_surplus_func, update_func, right_surplus_func):
    """
    :type left: collections.Iterable[U]
    :type right: collections.Iterable[T]
    :type compare_func: (U, T) -> int
    :type left_surplus_func: (U) -> None
    :type update_func: (U, T) -> None
    :type right_surplus_func: (T) -> None
    """
    while True:
        try:
            l = next(left)
        except StopIteration:
            l = None  # Evil hack, but acceptable for this example
        try:
            r = next(right)
        except StopIteration:
            r = None

        if l is None and r is not None:
            cmp_res = 1
        elif l is not None and r is None:
            cmp_res = -1
        elif l is None and r is None:
            return
        else:
            cmp_res = compare_func(l, r)

        if cmp_res == 0:
            update_func(l, r)
        elif cmp_res < 0:
            left_surplus_func(l)
            right = itertools.chain([r], right)  # aka right.unget(r)
        else:
            right_surplus_func(r)
            left = itertools.chain([l], left)  # aka left.unget(l)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to archive a similar result? I'm a little bit unhappy with my solution, as it depends on external side-effects of the functions. It would be nice to have a pure functional solution.

**Edit: This is my test case:**

```
creates = []
updates = []
deletes = []

def compare(a, obj):
    return cmp(int(a), obj)

def handle_left(a):
    creates.append(a)

def update(a, obj):
    updates.append((a, obj))

def handle_right(obj):
    deletes.append(obj)

left = list('12356')
right = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
compare_iterables_elemet_wise(iter(left), iter(right), compare, handle_left, update, handle_right)

assert creates == ['2', '5']
assert updates == [('1', 1), ('3', 3), ('6', 6)]
assert deletes == [4, 7]
```

I'd guess that I just need these three lists: `creates`, `updates` and `deletes`.

**Edit2: set operations:**

This is similar to my problem, except that the types of left and right differ:

```
left = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]

right = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7]

In [10]: set(left) - set(right)
Out[10]: {2, 5}

In [11]: set(right) - set(left)
Out[11]: {4, 7}


In [14]: set(right).intersection(set(left))
Out[14]: {1, 3, 6}
```

Comment: are the two lists having the same length? I guess not according to your problem? Would help if you give a simple generic example instead of your specific code.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: here you go.

Comment: what you try to achieve is not, from my point of view, obvious ... as such a  setdiff between lists (after conversion) can help on your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the `try` statements at the begining of your `while` loop by using the default argument of the `next` built-in function.

```
def compare_iterables_element_wise(left, right, compare_func,
                      left_surplus_func, update_func, right_surplus_func):

    l, r = next(left, None), next(right, None)
    while l or r:
        if l is None and r is not None:
            cmp_res = 1
        elif l is not None and r is None:
            cmp_res = -1
        else:
            cmp_res = compare_func(l, r)

        if cmp_res == 0:
            update_func(l, r)
            l, r = next(left, None), next(right, None)
        elif cmp_res < 0:
            left_surplus_func(l)
            l = next(left, None)
        else:
            right_surplus_func(r)
            r = next(right, None)
```

I would also suggest that `compare_func` handles the case where one of the argument is `None` so that you get rid of the first `if`.

From your second edit, the use of sets seems to be a good idea, providing you can cast your objects into a common type. You could have a `__hash__` method to associate an integer with each object and do your operations based on the `hash` value.