# Return a list after comparing 2 list and returning the count of occurrences in list1 elements that exist in list2

Tags: python, list, algorithm, set

What if I want to return the list of occurrence of the values in `list1` as compared to `list2` as below?

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I expect to get 0 occurrence of 1, 0 occurrence of 2, 0 occurrence of 3, 0 occurrence of 4, and 1 occurrence of 5; to have a new list as below,

```
new_list = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

See below by implementation. What am I doing wrong?

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def matchingStrings(list1, list2):
    count_all=Counter(list1)
    counts= {x: count_all[x] for x in list2 if x in list1 }
    list_output=list(counts.values())
    print(list_output)
    return list_output
    # Write your code here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    matchingStrings(list1,list2)
```

Output

[image]

Expected output

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly pass a set of he needed values to the `Counter` then iterate on the `list1` to get their count or 0

```
def matchingStrings(list1, list2):
    counts = Counter(list1)
    return [counts.get(value, 0) for value in list2]

print(matchingStrings(list1, list2))  # [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

Benchmark of `Counter` vs `list.count`

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

def matchingStrings(list1, list2):
    counts = Counter(list1)
    return [counts.get(value, 0) for value in list2]

def matchingStrings2(list1, list2):
    return [list1.count(a) for a in list2]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nb = 5000
    times = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(10):
        list1 = list(np.random.randint(0, 100, nb))
        list2 = list(np.random.randint(0, 100, nb))

        s = datetime.now()
        x1 = matchingStrings(list1, list2)
        times["counter"].append(datetime.now() - s)

        s = datetime.now()
        x2 = matchingStrings2(list1, list2)
        times["list"].append(datetime.now() - s)

    print(np.mean(times['list']) / np.mean(times['counter']))

    for key, values in times.items():
        print(f"{key:7s} => {np.mean(values)}")
```

Complexity of `Counter` solution is `2n` whereas `list.count` solution is `n²`

Here's a few numbers

```
nb = 1000                  # lists size
39.18844022169438          # counter 50 times faster
counter => 0:00:00.001263
list    => 0:00:00.049495

nb = 5000                  # lists size
481.512173128945           # counter 500 times faster
counter => 0:00:00.003327
list    => 0:00:01.601991

nb = 10000                 # lists size
1104.0679151061174         # counter 1000 times faster
counter => 0:00:00.004005
list    => 0:00:04.421792
```

Comment: Much better without all the `set` shenanigans.

Comment: @Franciskinyuru note that is completly much faster than list.count

Comment: `counts[value]` already evaluates to 0 if `value` is not in `counts`. You don't need to specify `counts.get(value, 0)` explicitly.

Comment: This is well noted since runtime also matters a lot

Comment: Better use `list`s of `int`s, as that's what the question uses (and it'll be faster, too).

Comment: @Stef if a key is not in a dict and you call `mydict[value]` it raises an error. not sure of what you mean so ?

Comment: @KellyBundy isn't what my benchmark code does ? list of int and the benchmark is clear no ? I could have make mistake, but tell me where. Counter is faster because you iterate on list1 ONCE, with list.count you do it N times, N being the size of list2, so that n²

Comment: @azro No, your `list` elements aren't `int` but `numpy.int64`. You can use `np.random.randint(0, 100, nb).tolist()` to get `int` elements. Counter is faster **if** N is large enough. We don't know whether it is. The OP showed lists of five elements and no indication that they actually have much larger lists. And in a similar case, where I think the OP even asked about efficiency, I once had my O(n) answer lose against an O(n^2) answer because it turned out the OP really actually only had tiny data (but I think many times). Better don't leave out the actually shown size from your benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

A small correction fixes that:

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def matchingStrings(list1, list2):
    count_all=Counter(list2)
    counts= {x: count_all[x] for x in list1 }
    list_output=list(counts.values())
    print(list_output)
    return list_output
    # Write your code here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    matchingStrings(list1,list2)
```

Comment: It's a bit awkward to have both `print` and `return` in function `matchingStrings`. Probably the function should only return, not print, and then you can print the return value in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: Also, I think you swapped list1 and list2. You should probably call `Counter` on `list1`, not `list2`, and use a list rather than a dict for variable `counts`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `count` method.

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
def matchingStrings(list1, list2):
    new_list = [list1.count(a) for a in list2]
    print(new_list)
    return new_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    matchingStrings(list1,list2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Nice but about 500 times slower than Counter solution I posted ;)

Comment: @azro I would answer the question with `counter` but If OP says that he has list with millions of elements.

Comment: @azro That's not true. It's actually several times *faster* than your Counter solution. Unless you're using other lists...