# Find if any element of list exists in another list in Python

Tags: python, list

The question is about a quicker, ie. more pythonic, way to test if any of the elements in an iterable exists inside another iterable.

What I am trying to do is something like:

`if "foo" in terms or "bar" in terms or "baz" in terms:
    pass`

But apparently this way repeats the 'in terms' clause and bloats the code, especially when
we are dealing with many more elements. So I wondered whether is a better way to do this in python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Check if one of the following items is in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740287/python-check-if-one-of-the-following-items-is-in-a-list)

Answer (score 5):

You could also consider in your special case if it is possible to use `set`s instead of iterables.  If both (`foobarbaz` and `terms`) are `set`s, then you can just write

```
if foobarbaz & terms:
    pass
```

This isn't particularly faster than your way, but it is smaller code by far and thus probably better for reading.

And of course, not all iterables can be converted to `set`s, so it depends on your usecase.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it applies to my use case. I should have used sets from the beginning. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Figured out a way, posting here for easy reference. Try this:

`if any(term in terms for term in ("foo", "bar", "baz")):
    pass`

Answer (score 3):

Faster than Alfe's answer, since it only tests for, rather than calculates the, intersection

```
if not set(terms).isdisjoint({'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}):
    pass
```