# python syntax for string in list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

```
if 'PASSED' in cell.value or 'FAILED' in cell.value or 'INVALID' in cell.value:
    Test.append(6)
```

What is a more concise way to do this? I want to make it do something like

`if cell.value in ('PASSED','INVALID', 'FAILED')`

but that doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if one of the following items is in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740287/how-to-check-if-one-of-the-following-items-is-in-a-list)

Comment: Why does this ```'hello' in ( 'hello', 'world' ) #returns True``` not work for you? Are you sure that ```cell.value``` is a string ?

Comment: If cell.value is a string then "if cell.value in ('PASSED','INVALID', 'FAILED'):" will absolutely work - what error did you get?

Comment: @dermen: clearly `cell.value` is a *larger* string which may *contain* any of those three strings.

Comment: @gkusner: that'll only work if `cell.value` is *exactly* one of those strings, but not if `cell.value` *contains* such a string; e.g. `cell.value` is a longer string like `"The tests results were INVALID"`. `'INVALID' in cell.value` is then true, but your test is not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, clear from the first section of code, but not from the second. But I guess one can infer the first section of code works implying cell.value is a larger string.. still a little unclear to me

Comment: @dermen: the second line doesn't work because the strings are larger, I'm not sure why it isn't clear.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ```"but that doesn't work"``` referring to the second line doesn't directly imply the first line of code works is all im saying

Comment: I guess the bottom line is cell.value is ambiguous here, and probably very easy to paste into the question post, especially since its not being described anywhere

Comment: sorry for being unclear, but yes cell.value is a larger string, so the answer below works. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
if any(s in cell.value for s in ('PASSED','INVALID', 'FAILED')):
```

This tests each string in turn, returning `True` as soon as a test passes.