# Pandas Create Columns From Rows in Other Data Frame with Criteria

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pos = pd.DataFrame({'Station(s)':[',1,2,,','0,1,2,3,4'],
                    'Position':['Contractor','President'],
                    'Site(s)':['A,B','A'],
                    'Item(s)':['1','1,2']
                   })

pos[['Position','Site(s)','Station(s)','Item(s)']]

pos

    Position    Site(s)     Station(s)  Item(s)
0   Contractor  A,B         ,1,2,,      1
1   President   A          0,1,2,3,4    1,2
```

and

```
sd = pd.DataFrame({'Site':['A','B','B','C','A','A'],
                   'Station(s)':[',1,2,,',',1,2,,',',,,,',',1,2,,','0,1,2,,',',,2,,'],
                   'Item 1':[1,1,0,0,1,0],
                   'Item 2':[1,0,0,1,1,1]})
sd[['Site','Station(s)','Item 1','Item 2']]

sd

    Site    Station(s)  Item 1  Item 2
0   A        ,1,2,,        1    1
1   B        ,1,2,,        1    0
2   B        ,,,,          0    0
3   C        ,1,2,,        0    1
4   A        0,1,2,,       1    1
5   A        ,,2,,         0    1
```

I'd like to end up with this:

```
    Contractor  President   Site(s)     Station(s)  Item 1  Item 2
0      1           1           A         ,1,2,,       1     1
1      1           0           B         ,1,2,,       1     0
2      0           0           B         ,,,,         0     0
3      0           0           C         ,1,2,,       0     1
4      0           1           A         0,1,2,,      1     1
5      1           1           A         ,,2,,        0     1

results = pd.DataFrame({'Contractor':[1,1,0,0,0,1],
                    'President':[1,0,0,0,1,1],
                   'Site(s)':['A','B','B','C','A','A'],
                   'Station(s)':[',1,2,,',',1,2,,',',,,,',',1,2,,','0,1,2,,',',,2,,'],
                   'Item 1':[1,1,0,0,1,0],
                   'Item 2':[1,0,0,1,1,1]})
results[['Contractor','President','Site(s)','Station(s)','Item 1','Item 2']]
```

based on this logic:

For each kind of position:

1. Create a new column in sd with the name of that position.
2. Make its value equal to 1 for each row in which the following conditions are met (else 0 for other rows):

   a. sd['Site'] contains at least 1 value in pos['Site(s)']

   b. sd['Station(s)'] contains at least 1 number found in pos['Station(s)'] but NO extra numbers

I started with this but was promptly beaten back into submission:

```
for i in pos['Position']:
    sd[i]= 1 if lambda x: 'x' if x for x in pos['Site(s)'] if x in sd['Site']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way the data is being stored -- in strings of comma-separated
values -- code is required to iterate through the rows, pick apart the values,
iterate through the other DataFrame and pick apart its values, then compare the
two, etc.... I don't see a way to really improve upon this situation as long as
the inputs retain the comma-separated values.

Given the constraints, I think [su79eu7k's
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37245696/190597) is quite good.

If, however, you buy into the idea that "tidy data" ([PDF](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf)) is better -- if you allow us
to change the starting point to be DataFrames in tidy format -- then there is a
different approach which may be more performant especially when `sd` has many
rows. The problem with using `sd.apply(check, axis=1)` is that under the hood it
uses a Python loop to iterate over the rows of `sd`. Calling `check` once for
every row can be relatively slow compared to equivalent code that takes
advantage of Panda's faster vectorized methods (like `merge` or `groupby`).
However, to use `merge` and `groupby` you need the data to be in tidy format.

So suppose instead of `pos` and `sd` we start with `tidypos` and `tidysd`. (At
the end of this post you'll find a runnable example which converts `pos` and `sd` to their tidy
equivalents.)

```
In [238]: tidypos
Out[238]: 
     Position Site Station
0  Contractor    A       1
1  Contractor    A       2
2  Contractor    B       1
3  Contractor    B       2
4   President    A       0
5   President    A       1
6   President    A       2
7   President    A       3
8   President    A       4

In [239]: tidysd
Out[239]: 
   index Site Station
0      0    A       1
1      0    A       2
2      1    B       1
3      1    B       2
4      3    C       1
5      3    C       2
6      4    A       0
7      4    A       1
8      4    A       2
9      5    A       2
```

`tidypos` and `tidysd` contain the same information as `pos` and `sd` (ignoring `Items` since they play no role in this problem.)
The difference mainly is that each row in `tidypos` and `tidysd` corresponds to one "observation". Each observation is independent of every other. 
Essentially, this boils down to simply splitting the comma-separated values so that each value ends up on a separate row.

Now we can join the two DataFrames based on the common columns, `Site` and `Station`:

```
In [241]: merged = pd.merge(tidysd, tidypos, how='left'); merged
Out[241]: 
    index Site Station    Position
0       0    A       1  Contractor
1       0    A       1   President
2       0    A       2  Contractor
3       0    A       2   President
4       1    B       1  Contractor
5       1    B       2  Contractor
6       3    C       1         NaN
7       3    C       2         NaN
8       4    A       0   President
9       4    A       1  Contractor
10      4    A       1   President
11      4    A       2  Contractor
12      4    A       2   President
13      5    A       2  Contractor
14      5    A       2   President
```

Now, each row in `merged` represents a match between a row of `tidysd` and a row
of `tidypos`. Therefore, the presence of a row implies that there was a match
between `sd['Site']` and `pos['Site']`, and moreover, a match between
`tidysd['Station']` and `tidypos['Station']`. In other words, for that row,
`sd['Station(s)']` must contain a number found in `pos['Station()']`. The only
critera we are not yet sure about is whether there are extra numbers in
`sd['Station(s)']` that do not appear in `pos['Station()']`.

We can find that out by counting the number of rows in `merged` for each `index`
and `Position` since each such row corresponds to a different `Station`. If this
number equals the total number of possible `Station`s for that `index` then
`sd['Station(s)']` contains no "extra numbers".

We can use `groupby/nunique` to count the number of `Stations` for each `index` and `Position`:

```
In [256]: pos_count = merged.groupby(['index', 'Position'])['Station'].nunique().unstack(); pos_count
Out[256]: 
Position  Contractor  President
index                          
0                2.0        2.0
1                2.0        NaN
4                2.0        3.0
5                1.0        1.0
```

and we can count the total number of `Station`s for each `index`:

```
In [243]: total_count = tidysd.groupby(['index'])['Station'].nunique(); total_count
Out[243]: 
index
0    2
1    2
3    2
4    3
5    1
Name: Station, dtype: int64
```

So that finally, we can assign 1's and 0's to the `Contractor` and `President` columns, 
based on the criterion `(pos_count[col] == total_count)`:

```
pos_count = pos_count.reindex(total_count.index, fill_value=0)
for col in pos_count:
    pos_count[col] = (pos_count[col] == total_count).astype(int)
pos_count = pos_count.reindex(sd.index, fill_value=0)
# Position  Contractor  President
# 0                  1          1
# 1                  1          0
# 2                  0          0
# 3                  0          0
# 4                  0          1
# 5                  1          1
```

If you really wish, you can then concatenate this result to the original `sd` to produce the exact desired result:

```
In [246]: result = pd.concat([sd, pos_count], axis=1); result
Out[246]: 
   Item 1  Item 2 Site Station(s)  Contractor  President
0       1       1    A     ,1,2,,           1          1
1       1       0    B     ,1,2,,           1          0
2       0       0    B       ,,,,           0          0
3       0       1    C     ,1,2,,           0          0
4       1       1    A    0,1,2,,           0          1
5       0       1    A      ,,2,,           1          1
```

but again, if you buy into the idea that data should be tidy, you should avoid packing multiple rows worth of data into a comma-separated string.

---

*How to tidy-up `pos` and `sd`*:

You can use the vectorized string methods, `.str.findall` and `.str.split` to
convert the comma-separated strings to lists of values. Then use list
comprehensions to iterate through the rows and lists to build `tidypos` and
`tidysd`.

Putting it all together,

```
import itertools as IT
import pandas as pd

pos = pd.DataFrame({'Station(s)':[',1,2,,','0,1,2,3,4'],
                    'Position':['Contractor','President'],
                    'Site(s)':['A,B','A'],
                    'Item(s)':['1','1,2']})

sd = pd.DataFrame({'Site':['A','B','B','C','A','A'],
                   'Station(s)':[',1,2,,',',1,2,,',',,,,',',1,2,,','0,1,2,,',',,2,,'],
                   'Item 1':[1,1,0,0,1,0],
                   'Item 2':[1,0,0,1,1,1]})

mypos = pos.copy()
mypos['Station(s)'] = mypos['Station(s)'].str.findall(r'(\d+)')
mypos['Site(s)'] = mypos['Site(s)'].str.split(r',')
tidypos = pd.DataFrame(
    [(row['Position'], site, station) 
     for index, row in mypos.iterrows() 
     for site, station in IT.product(
             *[row[col] for col in ['Site(s)', 'Station(s)']])], 
    columns=['Position', 'Site', 'Station'])

mysd = sd[['Site', 'Station(s)']].copy()
mysd['Station(s)'] = mysd['Station(s)'].str.findall(r'(\d+)')

tidysd = pd.DataFrame(
    [(index, row['Site'], station)
     for index, row in mysd.iterrows() 
     for station in row['Station(s)']], 
    columns=['index', 'Site', 'Station'])

merged = pd.merge(tidysd, tidypos, how='left')
pos_count = merged.groupby(['index', 'Position'])['Station'].nunique().unstack()
total_count = tidysd.groupby(['index'])['Station'].nunique()
pos_count = pos_count.reindex(total_count.index, fill_value=0)
for col in pos_count:
    pos_count[col] = (pos_count[col] == total_count).astype(int)
pos_count = pos_count.reindex(sd.index, fill_value=0)
result = pd.concat([sd, pos_count], axis=1)
print(result)
```

yields

```
   Item 1  Item 2 Site Station(s)  Contractor  President
0       1       1    A     ,1,2,,           1          1
1       1       0    B     ,1,2,,           1          0
2       0       0    B       ,,,,           0          0
3       0       1    C     ,1,2,,           0          0
4       1       1    A    0,1,2,,           0          1
5       0       1    A      ,,2,,           1          1
```

Comment: Incredible. Thanks again. The tidy data information is much appreciated. Unfortunately, I receive the data in an "untidy" state from the organization that provides the data, but I will certainly relay the information about tidy data to them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried roughly, you can improve below code.

```
sd['Contractor'] = 0
sd['President'] = 0

def check(x):
    for p in pos['Position'].tolist():
        if x['Site'] in pos.set_index('Position').loc[p, 'Site(s)'].split(','):
            ss = pd.Series(x['Station(s)'].split(',')).replace('', np.nan).dropna()
            ps = pd.Series(pos.set_index('Position').loc[p, 'Station(s)'].split(',')).replace('', np.nan).dropna()
            if not ss.empty and ss.isin(ps).all():
                x[p] = 1

    return x

print sd.apply(check, axis=1)


   Item 1  Item 2 Site Station(s)  Contractor  President
0       1       1    A     ,1,2,,           1          1
1       1       0    B     ,1,2,,           1          0
2       0       0    B       ,,,,           0          0
3       0       1    C     ,1,2,,           0          0
4       1       1    A    0,1,2,,           0          1
5       0       1    A      ,,2,,           1          1
```

Comment: For better performance, `ps` could be lifted outside of `check` (made a global or default parameter of `check`) so that it is computed only once instead of each time `check` is called.