# Pandas Pivot Table with Fancy Stacking

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

Given the following data frames:

```
results = pd.DataFrame({'Contractor':[1,1,0,0,0,1],
                    'President':[1,0,0,0,1,1],
                   'Item 1':[1,1,0,0,1,np.nan],
                   'Item 2':[1,0,0,1,0,1]})
results[['Contractor','President','Item 1','Item 2']]

results

    Contractor  President   Item 1  Item 2
0        1          1       1       1
1        1          0       1       0
2        0          0       0       0
3        0          0       0       1
4        0          1       1       0
5        1          1       NaN     1
```

and this for reference to items (see below):

```
    Position    Item(s)
0   Contractor  1
1   President   1,2
```

...I would like to pivot the data to produce this:

```
    Position    Overall%
0   Contractor  100
1   President   80
```

...based on this logic:

Because the president is concerned with items 1 and 2, there are 5 numbers to consider: (1 and 1) from item 1 and (1, 0, and 1) from item 2. The **sum across items** is 4 and the **count across items** is 5 (**do not count 'NaN'**), which gives 80%.

Because the contractor is only concerned with item 1, there are 2 numbers to consider: 1 and 1 - 'NaN' should not be counted - (from the rows of interest, respectively). Therefore, the sum is 2 out of the count, which is 2, which gives 100%

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

results = pd.DataFrame({'Contractor':[1,1,0,0,0,1],
                    'President':[1,0,0,0,1,1],
                   'Item 1':[1,1,0,0,1,np.nan],
                   'Item 2':[1,0,0,1,0,1]})
reference =  pd.DataFrame({'Position':['Contractor','President'],
                           'Item(s)':[(1,), (1,2)]})

longref = pd.DataFrame([('Item {}'.format(item), row['Position']) 
                        for index, row in reference.iterrows() 
                        for item in row['Item(s)']], columns=['Item', 'Position'])
melted = pd.melt(results, id_vars=['Item 1','Item 2'], var_name='Position')
melted = melted.loc[melted['value']==1]
melted = pd.melt(melted, id_vars=['Position'], 
                 value_vars=['Item 1','Item 2'], var_name='Item')
merged = pd.merge(longref, melted, how='left')
grouped = merged.groupby(['Position'])
result = (grouped['value'].sum() / grouped['value'].count())*100
result = result.rename('Overall%').reset_index()
print(result)
```

yields

```
     Position  Overall%
0  Contractor     100.0
1   President      80.0
```

---

**Explanation**: There is an article by [Hadley Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley)
([PDF](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf)) propounding the advantages
of making data "tidy".  The main tenet is that each row should
represent an "observation" and each column represent some factor or variable.

It frequently turns out that the tools you will need to express your calculation
will fall into place quite naturally once the data is tidy.
The difficulty of this problem largely comes from the data not being tidy.

Consider `results`:

```
In [405]: results
Out[405]: 
   Contractor  Item 1  Item 2  President
0           1     1.0       1          1
1           1     1.0       0          0
2           0     0.0       0          0
3           0     0.0       1          0
4           0     1.0       0          1
5           1     NaN       1          1
```

Instead of having separate columns for `Contractor` and `President`, it would be nicer to have one column called `Position`, since `Position` is the variable, and each observation or row can have one value for `Position` -- either a `Contractor` or a `President`. 
Similarly, `Item 1` and `Item 2` should be coalesced into a single column `Item`:

```
In [416]: melted
Out[416]: 
      Position    Item  value
0   Contractor  Item 1    1.0
1   Contractor  Item 1    1.0
2   Contractor  Item 1    NaN
3    President  Item 1    1.0
4    President  Item 1    1.0
5    President  Item 1    NaN
6   Contractor  Item 2    1.0
7   Contractor  Item 2    0.0
8   Contractor  Item 2    1.0
9    President  Item 2    1.0
10   President  Item 2    0.0
11   President  Item 2    1.0
```

`melted` contains the same information as `results`, but in a tidy format. The `value` column contains the values in `results[['Item 1', 'Item 2']]`. Each row corresponds to an "observation" where either `results['Contractor']` or result['President']` equals 1, since the calculation's logic only requires these values.

Similarly, instead of

```
In [407]: reference
Out[407]: 
  Item(s)    Position
0    (1,)  Contractor
1  (1, 2)   President
```

it would be tidier to have a DataFrame whose columns are `Item` and `Position`:

```
In [408]: longref
Out[408]: 
     Item    Position
0  Item 1  Contractor
1  Item 1   President
2  Item 2   President
```

Once you have the tidy version of your data in the form of `melted` and `longref`, 
calculating the desired result is fairly straight-forward:

```
merged = pd.merge(longref, melted, how='left')
#      Item    Position  value
# 0  Item 1  Contractor    1.0
# 1  Item 1  Contractor    1.0
# 2  Item 1  Contractor    NaN
# 3  Item 1   President    1.0
# 4  Item 1   President    1.0
# 5  Item 1   President    NaN
# 6  Item 2   President    1.0
# 7  Item 2   President    0.0
# 8  Item 2   President    1.0

grouped = merged.groupby(['Position'])
result = (grouped['value'].sum() / grouped['value'].count())*100
result = result.rename('Overall%').reset_index()
```

---

*How to tidy-up `reference` to make `longref`*:

Just iterate through the rows of `reference` and for each row iterate through the tuple of items to build the new DataFrame, `longref`:

```
longref = pd.DataFrame([('Item {}'.format(item), row['Position']) 
                        for index, row in reference.iterrows() 
                        for item in row['Item(s)']], columns=['Item', 'Position'])
```

---

*How to tidy-up `results` to make `melted`*:

It can be done with two calls to `pd.melt`. `pd.melt` converts "wide" format to "long" format DataFrames. It can coalesce multiple columns into a single column. For example, to coalesce the Contractor and President columns into a single Position column you could use:

```
melted = pd.melt(results, id_vars=['Item 1','Item 2'], var_name='Position')
# we only care about rows where Contractor or President value was 1. So use .loc to select those rows.
melted = melted.loc[melted['value']==1]
#     Item 1  Item 2    Position  value
# 0      1.0       1  Contractor      1
# 1      1.0       0  Contractor      1
# 5      NaN       1  Contractor      1
# 6      1.0       1   President      1
# 10     1.0       0   President      1
# 11     NaN       1   President      1
```

and similarly, to coalesce the `Item 1` and `Item 2` columns into a single `Item` column, use:

```
melted = pd.melt(melted, id_vars=['Position'], 
                 value_vars=['Item 1','Item 2'], var_name='Item')
#       Position    Item  value
# 0   Contractor  Item 1    1.0
# 1   Contractor  Item 1    1.0
# 2   Contractor  Item 1    NaN
# 3    President  Item 1    1.0
# 4    President  Item 1    1.0
# 5    President  Item 1    NaN
# 6   Contractor  Item 2    1.0
# 7   Contractor  Item 2    0.0
# 8   Contractor  Item 2    1.0
# 9    President  Item 2    1.0
# 10   President  Item 2    0.0
# 11   President  Item 2    1.0
```

Comment: Wow! Great points about tidy data. This is beyond what I was anticipating. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please consider responding to this related question if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245220/pandas-create-columns-from-rows-in-other-data-frame-with-criteria/37245696#37245696