# how to check if a positional element in a list of lists does not exist in another list of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find a reliable way to check if a positional list element in a `list2`  (all same length) does not exist in any `i for i in list1`?

This looks like the opposite of what I need:

[How to check if one of the following items is in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740287/how-to-check-if-one-of-the-following-items-is-in-a-list)

```
>>> list1 = [('1', '2', '3'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('4', '5', '6')]
>>> list2 = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('m', 'n', 'b'), ('p', 'q', '6')]
>>> print(any(z in [i[2] for i in list1] for z in [z for x,y,z in list2]))
True
```

Ideally I want `('m','n,'b')` of `list2` because `'b'` is not found in any 3rd element of `list1`, so how do I segregate it out?

Instead of 'any' I am looking for this sort of pseudo code:

```
print x,y,z from list2 if 'z' is not found in any 3rd position element in all the lists present in "list1"
```

Comment: You mean *third* element perhaps? With zero-based indexing, `object[2]` is the third element, not the second.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean, 0,1,2 so I am thinking 2nd (including 0th)

Comment: In English, enumerations don't start at 0. `object[2]` is the third element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a set of all third elements from the first list, then test your tuples from the second list against the set:

```
third_positions = {t[2] for t in list1}
[t for t in list2 if t[2] not in third_positions]
```

Storing the values to test again first is far more efficient, than to loop over all the values again each time.

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = [('1', '2', '3'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('4', '5', '6')]
>>> list2 = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('m', 'n', 'b'), ('p', 'q', '6')]
>>> third_positions = {t[2] for t in list1}
>>> print([t for t in list2 if t[2] not in third_positions])
[('m', 'n', 'b')]
```

If you must use `any()`, then that is possible too, but that incurs a loop over `list1` *for every tuple in `list2`*, so O(NM) instead of O(N):

```
[t for t in list2 if not any (t[2] == u[2] for u in list1)]
```