# How do I print elements of one list that are in another list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists that have a few similar value, what I want is to print out the values that are only in both lists. 
I tried a list comprehension but it gives me a boolean list:

```
a=[2,3,1,5,7]
b=[2,5,9,3,5,10]
c=[d in a for d in b]
print (c)
```

from this I get the results below:

```
[True, True, False, True, True, False]
```

but I wanted the numbers familiar in both lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if one of the following items is in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740287/how-to-check-if-one-of-the-following-items-is-in-a-list)

Comment: Have you considered using sets instead, they have features for such calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally take only the `d` that are in `a` from `b`:

```
c = [d for d in b if d in a]
# Here -----------^
```

Answer (score 1):

let us see this code :`[d in a for d in b]`, `d in a` will return `True` or `False` because it equal to

```
if d in a:
    return True 
else:
    return False
```

So the result of `[d in a for d in b]` is `[True, True, False, True, True, False]`

The best way to ***wanted the numbers familiar in both lists*** is:

```
a=[2,3,1,5,7]
b=[2,5,9,3,5,10]
print(list(set(a) & set(b))) # [2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `set` to compare the values, however I don't believe this preserves order:

```
c = set(a) & set(b)
print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in c))
```