# how to correctly build an expression with comparison operators and brackets?

Tags: python, algorithm

this not work well:

```
a = ['123','567','10', '223', '33']
for item in a:
    if ('5' or '1' or '2') in item:
        print(item)
```

I want to get any item in which there is at least one match with the numbers 1 or 2 or 5
My version is very cumbersome:

```
if '5' in item or '1' in item or '2' in item:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if one of the following items is in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740287/how-to-check-if-one-of-the-following-items-is-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any`,

```
a = ['123','567','10', '223']
for item in a:
    if any(i in item for i in ('5','1','2')):
        print(item)
```

Comment: Any reason you removed the acceptance?